# Cannot mount image of NTFS partition recovered through ddrescue

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs

The hard drive on my laptop has been giving me read errors, so I decided to back up the data on it.

I decided to use ddrescue to recover the data on the main NTFS partition. I first created a partition of a size slightly greater than the one I wanted to recover (about one or two Gb greater).
After more than two days of non-stop copying with around 400 read error messages, ddrescue had finished.

When I tried to mount the partition however, I read

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
```

I checked dmesg as was advised but could not find anything pertaining to the device besides the point where it was plugged in, only audit messages.

I then ran `ntfsfix`, with output:

```
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... NTFS signature is missing.
FAILED
Failed to startup volume: Invalid argument
NTFS signature is missing.
Trying the alternate boot sector
Unrecoverable error
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk.
```

I then attempted to run chkdsk on the partition. The output was as follows:

```
The type of the filesystem is RAW.
CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives.
```

I thought this would mean the partition is not formatted, which would be odd since the partition it was copied from was. To investigate this, I used `cmp` on both the device descriptor of the original partition and of the copy, and found they differed in the first byte.

My question is, what should I do to recover the data from my hard drive?

1. Is there a specific operation I should do on the recovered image?
2. Should I try to use ddrescue to recover the partition again, or even the whole drive?

And additionally, I would be interested in insight into what caused this issue in the first place.

Comment: Backing up the contents of that partition to a known good drive is a better option than what you're trying to do. But if you insist on it then read this and compare with what you did: https://www.technibble.com/guide-using-ddrescue-recover-data/

Comment: Should I use `cp` or is there a specific command for this purpose? I thought `ddrescue` was effectively doing that, just with added precautions for failing drives.

Comment: Quoting: *If there are any, it is possible that the damage could be enough to render Windows unstable when cloned to a new drive, depending on where the damage is.

**Sometimes running CHKDSK and SFC on the new drive afterwards will take care of it, sometimes not.** It’s a judgment call at this point. If the errors are significant, you may be better off proceeding with a fresh Windows install and a data transfer/recovery from the rescued image*

Comment: I see, it is possible that this image is corrupted. I can still access the old drive and boot on it; I will try to copy the data again, as I may have written to a block (something like `/dev/sdc1`) without `-f`. [This post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/496792/what-does-dd-write-when-it-encounters-a-input-output-error) seems to suggest `dd` would not be an appropriate choice, so I'll try `ddrescue` again, but I am open to other options.

Comment: Using `ddrescue` again, but this time with `-f` solved the issue. Thank you for your help!